# Get value From Previous or Next Rows Based on Condition from two or more columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using Pandas Python to calculate timedelta between rows which when it uses previous or next rows is based on conditions.

My table is like this
[sampel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIbsT.png)

I want to create timedelta column with this condition:
it gets value from previous rows when STATUS > status_before
and gets value from next rows when STATUS < status_after.

I tried several ways to do this, and mostly ended up with this error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

this one is one example of what I did:

```
if db.STATUS == 0 and db.status_before == 1:
   db.delta = db['REPORTDATE'].shift()
```

Any solutions?

Comment: amend your question to show your sample data as text not an image in line with SO guidelines

Comment: Yeah. I am sorry and I will update my question after I can get to my PC. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to get better quality answers always provide your sample data as text not images
- `np.where()` allows you to use conditional logic in an assignment
- your logic does not specify what value to use when condition is not met, so I've used **REPORTDATE**

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"REPORTDATE":pd.date_range("2021-06-18", freq="8h", periods=5), "NAMA":["WPP 571"]*5, 
              "PELABUHAN":(["PP Belawan","di laut"]*3)[1:6], "STATUS":([1,0]*3)[0:5],
             "ASAL":(["PP Belawan","di laut"]*3)[0:5], "IGNORED":[0]*5,
             "INSERTTIME":[pd.to_datetime("2021-06-24 09:26:35")]*5})



(
    df.assign(
        status_after=df["STATUS"].shift(-1), status_before=df["STATUS"].shift()
    ).assign(
        timedelta=lambda d: np.where(
            (d.STATUS == 0) & (d["status_before"] == 1),
            d["REPORTDATE"].shift(),
            d["REPORTDATE"],
        )
    )
)
```

#### output

|  | REPORTDATE | NAMA | PELABUHAN | STATUS | ASAL | IGNORED | INSERTTIME | status_after | status_before | timedelta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-06-18 00:00:00 | WPP 571 | di laut | 1 | PP Belawan | 0 | 2021-06-24 09:26:35 | 0 | nan | 2021-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-06-18 08:00:00 | WPP 571 | PP Belawan | 0 | di laut | 0 | 2021-06-24 09:26:35 | 1 | 1 | 2021-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-06-18 16:00:00 | WPP 571 | di laut | 1 | PP Belawan | 0 | 2021-06-24 09:26:35 | 0 | 0 | 2021-06-18 16:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-06-19 00:00:00 | WPP 571 | PP Belawan | 0 | di laut | 0 | 2021-06-24 09:26:35 | 1 | 1 | 2021-06-18 16:00:00 |
| 4 | 2021-06-19 08:00:00 | WPP 571 | di laut | 1 | PP Belawan | 0 | 2021-06-24 09:26:35 | nan | 0 | 2021-06-19 08:00:00 |

Comment: Thanks, this code works!. Just wondering can I merge this code with groupby? My original data contains unique group of data so I need to apply this code for each group.

Comment: pretty much,  you can use a `lambda` function in `groupby().apply()` or `groupby().transform()`